# concave, not strictly concave

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

How can I prove that $\sqrt{xy}$ is concave, not strictly concave?
I tried to derivative twice $f''(x)$, but it becomes negative which is the definition for a strictly concave.

Comment: But $$\sqrt{xy}=f(x,y)$$

Comment: Yes, thats true. And therefore I do not know how to prove that f(x,y) = sqrt(xy) is concave, not strictly concave

Comment: So you do not do the second derivative, you do something involving the $2 \times 2$ matrix of all second partial derivatives.

Comment: see here https://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/cvn/t

Comment: For "not strictly concave", note how it behaves along $x=y$.

Answer (score -1):

$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial_x\partial_y}f(x,y)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{xy}}$$
Is this what you tried?

Comment: Yes, but how can I prove that this is concave, not strictly concave

Comment: You have to find a region in which is is not concave

Comment: How can I find the region?

Comment: Like you said, for the second differential you find an area in which it is positive

Comment: But it is concave (for $x, y \ge 0$).

Comment: are we only defining the function for real, as if not we can include where $x,y<0$. Also, is it concave at $x=y=0$?

Comment: It's wrong to say a function is concave **at** a point.  Concavity is a property of a function on a convex set.  This one is concave on the convex set $\{(x,y): x \ge 0,\; y \ge 0\}$.  That includes $x=y=0$.

Comment: I am not suggesting concavity at a single point, but asking whether $x=0$ can be included in the range